# Adding fields to response json in spring boot get method

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have the service that gives data from repository to rest controller:

```
@Service
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And also rest controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class TaskController {
@Autowired
private TaskService taskService;

```
    @GetMapping
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return taskService.getAllTasks();
    }
}
```

My task is to return not only all the tasks but two fields two - todo tasks count and ready tasks count. I know how find this count from db. But what is the proper way to add this fields to response json? Response json must look like:

```
{
  [
    {
      "createTime": null,
      "updateTime": null,
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "title": "todo-task",
      "description": "blabla",
      "priority": "HIGH",
      "done": false,
    },
    {
      "createTime": null,
      "updateTime": null,
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "title": "done-task",
      "description": "blabla",
      "priority": "HIGH",
      "done": true,
    }
  ],
  todoCount: 1,
  doneCount: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by creating new model to be returned by the Controller and set your  todoCount and doneCount values:

```
 @GetMapping
    public TasksModel getAllTasks() {
// get todoCount and doneCount values
          TasksModel tasksModel = new TasksModel();
          tasksModel.setTaskModelList(taskService.getAllTasks())
          tasksModel.setTodoCount(todoCount);
          tasksModel.setDoneCount(doneCount); 

        return taskModel;
    }
```

and  TasksModel  is :

```
class TasksModel  {
     
     List<Task> taskModelList;
     int todoCount;
     int doneCount;

//getter
//setter

}
```